# How to completely uninstall grafana?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, grafana

In Ubuntu 14.04, I installed grafana like below:

```
dpkg -i grafana_4.1.2-1486989747_amd64.deb
```

I am trying to uninstall it.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove grafana
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove grafana
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
locate grafana and manually remove files and folder
```

But still while reinstall it old templates is there.

While reinstall:

```
dpkg -i grafana_4.1.2-1486989747_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package grafana.
(Reading database ... 68772 files and directories currently installed.)
 .................
 ......................
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge grafana` removes Grafana and all dependencies and temp files.

Answer (score 16):

Uninstall just grafana:

```
sudo apt-get remove grafana
```

Uninstall grafana and its dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove grafana
```

For More details refer: http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/g/grafana/uninstall/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. You need to use the commands you referenced, 'locate grafana' and remove every instance returned. You can use the python script I wrote as pasted below. I can't guarantee that its the best way to write but it gets the job done. This completely removes grafana.

```
import os
import time
import subprocess

print('------------------------------------')
print('...Removing Grafana...\n\n')
os.system("sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove grafana -y && sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove grafana -y")
time.sleep(1)
print('------------------------------------')
print('...Cleaning Up...\n\n')
os.system("sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove")
time.sleep(1)
print('------------------------------------')
print('...Checking Left-Overs...\n\n')
os.system("sudo updatedb")
time.sleep(1)

cmd = "sudo locate grafana"
openCmd = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
fromCmd, stderr = openCmd.communicate()
cmds = fromCmd.split('\n')
print('------------------------------------')
print('...Removing Left-Overs...\n\n')

for cmd in cmds[:-1]:
    print('----------')
    print('Removing: '+str(cmd))
    os.system('sudo rm -r '+ str(cmd))

print('------------------------------------')
print('All Done!\n\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Error found in python program below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File line 21, in <module>
    cmds = fromCmd.split('\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Solved with

```
cmds = fromCmd.decode().split('\n')
```

See
[Cannot split, a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829364/cannot-split-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str)