# Cannot split, a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, string, shell, decode

I am trying to write a tshark (or any shell command for that matter) to a file. I've tried using `decode` and `encode` but it still yells at me that the `split` method cannot use the datatype.

My attempts are still in the code as comments, after the "capturing stopped" line. I have also tried `r`, `a` and `a+` as the `open` modes  but I actually get output with the `ab+` mode used here so I opted to keep it. Even using `a+` mode said `"blah"` was bytes. I would like to keep the file appended with the output.

```
import subprocess
import datetime

x="1"
x=input("Enter to continue. Input 0 to quit")
while x != "0":
    #print("x is not zero")
    blah = subprocess.check_output(["tshark -i mon0 -f \"subtype probe-req\" -T fields -e wlan.sa -e wlan_mgt.ssid -c 2"], shell=True)
    with open("results.txt", 'ab+') as f:
        f.write(blah)
    x=input("To get out enter 0")
print("Capturing Stopped")

# blah.decode()
#blah = str.encode(blah)

#split the blah variable by line
splitblah = blah.split("\n")

#repeat  for each line, -1 ignores first line since it contains headers
for value in splitblah[:-1]:

    #split each line by tab delimiter
    splitvalue = value.split("\t")

#Assign variables to split fields
MAC = str(splitvalue[1])
SSID = str(splitvalue[2])
time = str(datetime.datetime.now())

#write and format output to results file
with open("results.txt", "ab+") as f:
    f.write(MAC+" "+SSID+" "+time+"\r\n")
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If your question boils down to this:

> I've tried using decode and encode but it still yells at me that the split method cannot use the datatype.

The error at hand can be demonstrated by the following code:

```
>>> blah = b'hello world'  # the "bytes" produced by check_output
>>> blah.split('\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

In order to split `bytes`, a `bytes` object must also be provided.  The fix is simply:

```
>>> blah.split(b'\n')
[b'hello world']
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `decode()` correctly: either in two steps (if you want to reuse `blah`):

```
blah = blah.decode()
splitblah = blah.split("\n")
# other code that uses blah
```

or inline (if you need it for single use):

```
splitblah = blah.decode().split("\n")
```

Your issue with using `decode()` was that you did not use its return value. Note that `decode()` does **not** change the object (`blah`) to assign or pass it to something:

```
# WRONG!
blah.decode()
```

**SEE ALSO:**
[`decode`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) docs.

Answer (score -1):

For python3, you should use this kind of pattern (after moving from python2)

```
for line in res2.content.splitlines():
   
    line = line.decode()
```

you will not get the below error

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: This looks essentially the same as Timur's earlier answer.