# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when splitting lines from .gz file

Tags: python, string, split, typeerror

I have a gz file **sample.gz**.

```
This is first line of sample gz file.
This is second line of sample gz file.
```

I read this .gz file and then split it line by line. Once I have individual lines I further split it into parts with whitespace as separator.

```
import gzip
logfile = "sample.gz"
with gzip.open(logfile) as page:
    for line in page:
        string = line.split(" ")
        print(*string, sep = ',')
```

I am expecting output like

```
This,is,first,line,of,sample,gz,file.
This,is,second,line,of,sample,gz,file.
```

But insted of the above result, I am receiving TypeError:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Why is the split function not working as it is supposed to?

Comment: You have a comma instead of a dot in `string = line,split(" ")`

Comment: Because, as the error message tells you, you are passing a string, not a bytes-like object to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python read csv line from gzipped file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624803/python-read-csv-line-from-gzipped-file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50829888/15923186 Here's a direct answer to your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Split, A bytes-like object is required, not 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829364/cannot-split-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str)

Comment: @Gameplay no it is not comma, it is a dot. The stackoverflow.com/a/50829888/15923186 did got rid of the error, but then it appends the 'b' for every item in the list. Before i could try the 'Cannot Split, A bytes-like object is required, not 'str'' i tried my luck with link shared by mkrieger1.

Thank you very much for looking into this and suggesting those solutions. I did learn a couple of things. Thank you.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you very much for sharing that link. I got exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you guys see the comments above there are couple of approaches which can be used. I followed [Python read csv line from gzipped file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624803/python-read-csv-line-from-gzipped-file) suggested by
mkrieger1 and came up with below solution.

```
import gzip
logfile = "sample.gz"
with gzip.open(logfile) as page:
    for line in page:
        string = line.decode('utf-8').split(' ')
        print(*string, sep = ',')
```

Thanks for quick response here.

Answer (score 2):

[By default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open), `gzip.open` opens files in binary mode. This means that reading returns `bytes` objects, and `bytes` objects can only be split on other `bytes` objects, not on strings.

If you want strings, use the `mode` and `encoding` arguments to `gzip.open`:

```
with gzip.open(logfile, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as page:
    ...
```