# How to fix error switching code from python2 to python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i'm a streamer trying to make a twitch plays mod, and im struggling with one error to fix. The original source code was written in python 2.7, but im trying to do this in python 3.11.
The code is:

```
    if self.check_has_message(data):
        return [self.parse_message(line) for line in filter(None, data.split('\r\n'))];
```

gave error code:

```
typeerror: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I tried doing:

if self.check_has_message(data):

```
  return [self.parse_message(line) for line in filter(None, data.decode('utf-8').split('\r\n'))];
```

did not work.

I have no idea what im doing with this tbh but any help is great!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "D:\twitchplays\wituz\main.py", line 18, in 
new_messages = t.twitch_recieve_messages();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\twitchplays\wituz\twitch.py", line 73, in twitch_recieve_messages
return [self.parse_message(line) for line in filter(None, data.split('\r\n'))];
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Try `b'\r\n'`, might work.

Comment: @KurtisRader i did actually do research on google, but to no avail with this error. Ive been testing different things for an hour but still not getting anything

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried and it gave some new error code that google just says im opening the file wrong (im not opening any fille)

        


if self.check_has_message(data):
            return [self.parse_message(line) for line in filter(None, data.decode('utf-8').split(b'\r\n'))]

Comment: @Silph48 does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-handling-file-conte

Comment: @SurajShourie not really. I have no indication of what part i need to convert to or from binary, ive tried line, filter, data, and what mark said but nothing is working

Comment: Does the traceback really implicate the line of code you put in your question? Because I don't see anything about that line that would cause that error. Also, are you really sure you want to split on the string `\r\n`? That won't split if only a newline is present. Presumably it is the `self.parse_message()` method that is causing the error because `data.split()` wouldn't cause it.

Comment: i can copy the whole traceback. i just put it on the bottom up there. is there another option besides splitting the data here?

Comment: *"is there another option besides splitting the data here?"* - You haven't provided enough context for anyone to answer that.  My advice would be to use the python debugger to figure out exactly what is required to be "a bytes-like object".  Understanding the problem will help you work out how to solve it.

Comment: @StephenC what sort of context is needed here to help show the answer?

Comment: Read the rest of my comment.   Also re: "I have no idea what I'm doing with this":  you should probably working on >that< problem.

Comment: @StephenC im trying to read this but i have to be honest no idea what any of this means, im not an expert in python and its just tracebacks and stuff that ive never seen. Im sorry but like i dont know this-

Comment: @KurtisRader its showing with the red arrows that the data.split is whats causing it.

Comment: That's what I am trying to say ... you should be working on your python expertise ... so that you can solve this kind of problem for yourself.  As it is, the only way someone could help you is if you sent them your entire application, input data, etc so that they could *reproduce the error* for themselves.  That is most likely impractical.

Comment: @StephenC do you reccomend i just run it in 2.7 then if i cant fix it this way?

Comment: I'm not recommending anything.  Apart from what I've already said.

Comment: "im trying to read this but i have to be honest no idea what any of this means, im not an expert in python and its just tracebacks and stuff that ive never seen. Im sorry but like i dont know this" - then you should *follow a tutorial from the beginning and properly learn Python*, rather than trying to struggle with a project like this. Adapting legacy code from Python 2.x, in general, is an advanced skill that requires a superior understanding. You need to first develop at least basic [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) skills.

Comment: If you are confronted with a line of code that has multiple things in it that you don't understand, you should first try to break the logic apart into separate steps. At the very least, try to *test* what each part does in isolation. For example: can you find a way to *find out* what the value of `data` is, *before* this line of code? *What happens* if you try just the `data.split('\r\n')` part by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, learn [how to format a literal block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). See [Cannot split, a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829364/cannot-split-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str). The error message is misleading because you are using a string to split a byte array. Change the `'\r\n'` to `b'\r\n'`.

```
>>> b"a\nb".split("\n")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>>> b"a\nb".split(b"\n")
[b'a', b'b']
```

I also recommend learning to add print statements at strategic points in your code to understand what type of object is being operated on. For example:

```
>>> print(b"a\nb")
b'a\nb'
>>> print("a\nb")
a
b
>>> print(type("a\nb"))
<class 'str'>
>>> print(type(b"a\nb"))
<class 'bytes'>
```

Comment: Holy cow thank you so much! self.parse_message(line.decode('utf-8'')) and that fixed it

Comment: Please read [answer] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. If you find a duplicate link, vote to close the question as a duplicate - don't write an answer and cite the duplicate. If there are formatting issues, edit the question yourself if you can fix them, and otherwise comment to ask OP to do it, and/or vote to close as unclear. Meta commentary does not belong in answers.